# jQuery map() returns object instead of array

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
var selectedTitles = $("#js-otms-titles-table .select_title :checkbox:checked").map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-titleId');
});
console.log("Selected titles");
console.log(selectedTitles);
```

I expect that result will be an array. However I receive object like:

```
Object["55a930cd27daeaa6108b4f68", "55a930cd27daeaa6108b4f67"]
```

Is there a special flag to pass to the function? In [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) they are talking about arrays as a return value. Did I miss something?

jQuery 1.11.2

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`$(selector).map()` always returns  jQuery object.

To get array from jQuery object use `get()`

```
var selectedTitles = $("#js-otms-titles-table .select_title :checkbox:checked").map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-titleId');
}).get();
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to call `.get()` on the final result. jQuery's `.map()` function returns a jQuery object (which can be convenient at times). `.get()` will fetch the underlying array that it's built on.

See http://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: What is the difference between http://api.jquery.com/map/ and http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/ ? I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: One works on a jQuery object (generally elements), the other on a plain object or array.

Answer (score 7):

The setup:

```
var a = array(1, 2, 3);
var f = function () { return process_each(this); };
var selector;   // e.g. "div.class" or $("div#id1, div#id2, div#id3")
```

Ways to map*:

`$.map(a, f)` - **array** in - **array** out

`$(selector).map(f)` - **jQuery** object in - **jQuery** object out

`$(selector).map(f).get()` - **jQuery** object in - **array** out (since jQuery 1.0)

`$(selector).map(f).toArray()` - **jQuery** object in - **array** out (since jQuery 1.4)

*In this context, to *map* means to process the items in your collection (array or jQuery object), one at a time with your function, and to output a collection (array or jQuery object) of the return values.